# bool __builtin_sadd_overflow (int a, int b, int *res) not declared

Tags: gcc, built-in

I found the "integer overflow builtins" in the gcc manual, but it is not known to the compiler

```
'__builtin_sadd_overflow' was not declared in this scope
```

Called using

```
int x=0x7fffffff;
__builtin_sadd_overflow(2,x, &x);
```

The compiler version is

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
```

on i686.

Here is the manual: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html

Comment: Maybe this is a gcc 4.9 or gcc 5 thing ?

Comment: You need to specify where in which manual you saw that (give the link). By default, gcc gives you the doc of the development version that hasn't been released yet. You want to look at the manual for a specific release.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: How strange, they should give me the latest stable by default.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/gcc/C-Extensions.html does not mention overflow builtins.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: This the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/gcc/C-Extensions.html (documentation for the 4.8.3 release) does not mention the overflow builtins. The unversioned address https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html corresponds to the documentation for the development version of gcc (the future gcc-5). You can wait until March or April, or start playing with a snapshot, or use [clang's equivalent](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#multiprecision-arithmetic-builtins).